# Spring Security Rest Token Authentication - Filter does not run

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, filter

I'm building a REST application using Spring 4 and java configs (without any xml file).

Here some actual code:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {ApplicationConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Besides that I'm securing the WebService with Token Authentication, so I have a Filter to deal with the token and properly get the user by his token and put the user object into the `SecuriryContext`. Here is some code of the `Filter`:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

private String tokenHeader = "X-Auth-Token";

@Autowired
private TokenUtils tokenUtils;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
@Autowired
public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);
    String username = this.tokenUtils.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);

    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (this.tokenUtils.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

}
```

I'm using Spring Security, and here is my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private EntryPointUnauthorizedHandler unauthorizedHandler;

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationTokenFilter authTokenFilter;


  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }


  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
      .csrf()
        .disable()
      .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(this.unauthorizedHandler)
        .and()
      .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()    
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity
      .addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

}
```

My problem is that the Filter's `doFilter()` does not run. Any help?

PS: Using SpringBoot is not an option. I want to do that without using the spring boot auto configurations.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding filter not as a component, you do it like a simple object, which is created by reflection somewhere in ServletContext which knows nothing about Spring.
You can add you filter to SpringSecurityFilterChain in security configurations if you use Spring Security

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private YourFilter yourFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
           .addFilterBefore(yourFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you don't use Spring Security you may wanna create some filter as a chain of responsibility and add your beans-filters to it

Comment: Should I also remove the annotation @Component from my Filter?

Comment: If you want your filter as a bean and want it's fields Autowired, it should still be annotated as @Component of course =)

Comment: Not working, yet. See my edited question with the spring security code. Thanks

Comment: remove this 
`servletContext.addFilter("AuthenticationTokenFilter", AuthenticationTokenFilter.class);`

Comment: Edited the question. Now the filter does not run!

Comment: Did you add springSecurityFilterChain as a filter?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: In your WebAppInitializer you should override method onStartup and add this: `servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");`